# Как выровнять две группы объектов по отношению друг к другу?

Tags: illustrator

Как выровнять две группы объектов по отношению друг к другу в Adobe illustrator?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделите обе группы и кнопками выравнивания (сверху):
[image: кнопки сверху]

Например, вертикально по центру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]